# Symmetry in double integrals MUST be used if we have symmetry in the region?

Tags: symmetry, multiple-integral

I want to evaluate the integral
$$\int\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dA$$ on a region R where R is the region enclosed by the 2 circles $$x^2+y^2=a^2$$ $$x^2+y^2=b^2$$ $$a<b$$
My question is :
Do we have to use the symmetry ? or not ? 
My teacher said that we MUST use the symmetry in all problems of multiple integrals if we have symmetry over the region of integration , otherwise it will be wrong! But I do not know why ?! I am not convinced  ..

I used polar coordinates , if I do not use symmetry 
$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{r=a}^{r=b}\cos(\theta)\ r \ dr\  d\theta \ =0$$
If I use symmetry :
$$4\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/2}\int_{r=a}^{r=b}\cos(\theta)\ r \ dr\  d\theta \ =2(b^2-a^2)$$

Which solution is right and why ?
I think that we CAN NOT use symmetry here because the function $f(x,y)$ inside the integration is not even ! also when we used the polar coordinates : we have $\cos(\theta)$ in the integration which has values that do not repeat themselves for each quadrant! I see that we can use symmetry if the function inside integration does not depend on theta only ..

I think that we generally do not have to use symmetry except if we have symmetry in the function also not only the region of integration as my teacher said! I think that symmetry can help us to get the solution quickly but if we use it in a right way ..

Comment: What do you mean by "use the symmetry"? Which symmetry are you talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but there isn't any symmetry that allows you to say that this particular integral is the same in every quadrant, so your first solution is right. Of course if you can exploit some symmetry you should do it, but this is not the case, and anyway it just makes your job easier, but not exploiting it will not end up in a wrong result.

Comment: I mean instead of integrating from 0 to 2pi , we integrate from 0 to pi/2 and multiply by 4 ... the teacher said this must be done since we have symmetry in region (circle: each quadrant has a function of same shape) ..But I think we can use symmetry since the function f(x,y) inside integral is not even  / depend on theta in polar .

Comment: Yes this is my opinion that the first solution is right and this is what I am convinced with : " Not exploiting it will not end up in a wrong result" ..although my teacher said we must use it and that the second solution is the right ! ..  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The symmetry you tried to exploit is the wrong one: you can see that the function isn't the same in every quadrant, instead, changing the sign of $x$ changes the sign of the whole function. Your evaluation of the integral is correct (in the first case) but knowing this you can use a symmetry argument to conclude that the integral must be $0$ without calculating it, can you see it?

Comment: I think this is like single integral , when we say that integrating odd function from -a to a gives zero .. Here we integrate the function over the right side of x-y plane , we will get a specific value , then we integrate the function over the left side of x-y plane , we will get the same value with negative sign. so the result is zero ?

Comment: Exactly that! You can try to formulate it in polar coordinates if you want, but this argument is perfectly fine.